# How can i hide a tooltip for one dataseries in d3js?

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

My tooltip should hide if the mouse is over the data 'white'.. But i don't know how to do this

Here is my code:

```
  state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
  .call(d3.helper.tooltip()
            .attr({class: 'tooltip2'})                  
            .text(function(d, i){ return d.name + ': '+ (-((d.y0) - (d.y1))) ; })
        );
```

dataseries:

```
 State, White , FA Nicht gebucht, FA gebucht
 07.10.2014,24,1,0
 08.10.2014,24,1,0
 13.10.2014,22,3,0
 14.10.2014,24,1,0
 15.10.2014,21,4,0
 16.10.2014,15,10,1
 17.10.2014,12,13,0
 20.10.2014,17,8,0
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with d3.helper.tooltip, but my general strategy would be to make opacity = 0 whenhovering over "white".  Im not sure what the syntax would be for helper.tooltip, I don't know what kind of structure it creates in the DOM, but the principle would be: .style("opacity", function (d) if(d.name == "white"){return 0;} else {return 1;}).

Comment: thanks, but don't work..

Comment: Filter the selection before calling the tooltip: `.filter(function(d) { return d.name !== "white"; }).call(d3.helper.tooltip())`.